# PHP regexp for /prefix/action(/id)

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to build a regexp that would match both strings:

```
/prefix/action
```

and

```
/prefix/action/43
```

but not

```
/prefix/action/
```

or

```
/prefix/action43
```

where 43 can be anything like [0-9]+, only if preceded by a slash

I also want to capture the number (not the slash), if any, as a named group.

```
~/prefix/action/?(?P<itemID>[0-9]+)?~
```

This expression does match, except for a condition that numbers must be preceded by a slash, all my attempts at adding lookahead or lookbehind assertions failed on this one.

I do understand that with additional external processing the task can be solved, but I'm looking for a regexp solution only. Thank you for understanding.

Your suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Solved by:

```
~/prefix/action(?:/(?P<itemID>[0-9]+))?~
```

Comment: etranger, instead of appending `- solved` to the subject title of your question, please accept codaddict's answer as the correct one.

Comment: I couldn't for a few minutes after posting, I have now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about making both the `/` and the following number optional?

```
^/prefix/action(?:/[0-9]+)?$
```

To capture the optional number in a named group add `(?P<itemID>...)` around the number regex:

```
^/prefix/action(?:/(?P<itemID>[0-9]+))?$
```

Also note that I've added start and end anchors, which were missing in *your* regex. Without them you'll get a match if you have a sub-string of the input that matches the regex.

Comment: Could you please specify how to mix this with a named group?